# Using FireDAC MS Access services (Delphi XE6)

Tags: delphi, ms-access, odbc, delphi-xe6, firedac

I am using the TFDMSAccessService component to create a MS Access database.

This works in the 32 bit compiler and obviously uses the 32 bit ODBC components to create the database.
However, for a 64 bit version there are no ODBC drivers if you have Office 2010 installed. I have tried to install the 64 bit version, but it means that I need to uninstall the whole Office pack and then install the Access Data drivers. So either way you cannot have both.

Is there a way of running the TFDMSAccessService with 32 Bit ODBC but the application compiled in 64 bit compiler?
Or even better: detecting which ODBC is installed and make the FDMSAccessService use the correct drivers?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to use a 32bit driver from a 64bit application, so you need a 64bit version of the driver installed or otherwise you'll need to compile at 32 bit your application .